# how to have 3 different row designs in the same ListView?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, listview

I have custom ListView that contains 60 items, and I have a 3 differnet row design and the 3 rows contains the same textView but with different background here is the xmle code to understand it better:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/abilityBlue" 
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="23dp"
android:paddingRight="1dp"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:background="@drawable/ability_blue_btn"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/abilityGreen" 
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="23dp"
android:paddingRight="1dp"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:background="@drawable/ability_green_btn"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/abilityYellow" 
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="23dp"
android:paddingRight="1dp"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:background="@drawable/ability_yellow_btn"/>
```

so I wanted to know how could I make for an example each 20 items with the different textview.
Thanks

MY adapter:

```
class Ability extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
Context context;
String[] titleArray;

Ability(Context c,String[] Names)
{
    super(c,R.layout.ability_btn,R.id.abilityBlue,Names);
    this.context=c;
    this.titleArray=Names;
}

class MyViewHolder
{
    TextView myText;

    MyViewHolder(View v)
    {
        myText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.abilityBlue);

    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView; 
    MyViewHolder holder = null;
    if(row==null)
    {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ability_btn, parent, false);
       holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
       row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    holder.myText.setText(titleArray[position]);


    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: Use a single TextView as your custom row. Then, **in the adapter**, **if** the index is **> 40** (41+) then set its background resource to yellow; **else, if** it is **> 20** (21+), set its background resource to green. Otherwise (1 - 20) don't change it (blue). Very easy. Just an `if ... elseif`

Comment: @DerGolem can you tell me how to do that in a more detailed answer, please :)

Comment: The RecyclerView which released with Lollipop would be a better choice.

Comment: You must always set the color as views get recycled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a single TextView as your custom row.

Something like:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ability" 
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="23dp"
    android:paddingRight="1dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/ability_blue_btn"
/>
```

Then, **in the adapter** (in the `getView()` method), **if** the index is **> 40** (41+) then set its background resource to yellow; **else, if** it is **> 20** (21+), set its background resource to green.
Otherwise (1 - 20) don't change it (blue).

Something like this:

```
final TextView txtAbility = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ability);

// Change the item color
// This one is based on the TextView's text value, since mine was a game score.
// You can change the int ability to match the item position.
final int ability = Integer.parseInt((String) txtAbility.getText());
if (ability > 40)
{
    txtAbility.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ability_yellow_btn);
}
else
    if (ability > 20)
    {
        txtAbility.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ability_green_btn);
    }
}
```

Very easy. Just an `if ... elseif`

**[EDIT]**

---

Your code:

holder.myText.setText(titleArray[position]);

Change it to:

```
holder.myText.setText(titleArray[position]); // same as yours, just add the lines below.

// Change the item color
if (position > 39) // position starts at 0
{
    holder.myText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ability_yellow_btn);
}
else
    if (position > 19) // position starts at 0
    {
        holder.myText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ability_green_btn);
    }
}
```

Comment: where do I add the the second part of the code in the OnCreate or in the adapter

Comment: In the adapter, i mentioned that.

Comment: I am sorry I know the question is really stupid, but where in the adapter in the getView method or where exactly

Comment: I don't know how to add it to my adapter, so I edited my question and typed my adapter, so can you tell me how to add it my adapter, please

Comment: ok it's working fine but when I scroll down then I go up the background changes and they become random

Comment: Weird. Are you testing on an emulator or on a physical device?

Comment: What happens on a real device?

Comment: Probably the issue happens in the check `if(row==null)`. I'd remove that check and its else branch (comment it out, so you can easily roll back).

Comment: I don't have a real device available right now, and I don't understand, you want me to remove the if and else statement?

Comment: Only leave the **4 lines** inside the if block - remove all what is surrounding these lines (if, else, all the brackets and the else contents too).

Comment: I am getting this warning "Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter: Should use View Holder pattern (use recycled view passed into this method as the second parameter) for smoother scrolling"

Comment: A warning is not an error. Just do a trial (I suspect that the recycling is doing some weirdness). If it crashes, restore it as before.

Answer (score 0):

This is a full example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0 ; i<60; i++)
    {
        arr.add("test"+String.valueOf(i));
    }
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this , R.layout.activity_main , arr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/tvtextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomAdapter

```
package com.example.nayraahmed.stackoverflow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

ArrayList<String> Info;
private Context context;

CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    Info = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    EventItemHolder eventHolder;
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        eventHolder = new EventItemHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

        eventHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtextView);


        view.setTag(eventHolder);
    } else {
        eventHolder = (EventItemHolder) view.getTag();

    }

    String eItem = (String) this.Info.get(position);
    if(position < 20)
        eventHolder.title.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    else if(position>=20 && position<40)
        eventHolder.title.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    else
        eventHolder.title.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    eventHolder.title.setText(eItem);

    return view;
}

private static class EventItemHolder {
    TextView title;
}
}
```

hope it'll help

Comment: it's not working properly, the blue background is no longer there, it's only the green an yellow, and after wach textview there is 2 extra empty textview one with the green backrgound and one with the yellow one, and if I scroll to the bottom app stops responding

Comment: I have tested the code and it is correct. Have you made any edits in it ??

Comment: I just changed the setBackgroundColor to setBackgroundRecources(R.drawable.ability_green_btn) since the difference is not only in the color

Comment: I have edited the code of the customAdapter class ,try it. I hope it'll work correct with you

Comment: What is the number of items are you populating in the listview ?
if they are less than 60 items the code won't work correctly